# How to invalidate config or service cache

Tags: caching, configuration

I have a service wich is loading a config at construct time:

```
class MyService {
  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
    $config = $config_factory->get('my.config');
    ...
  }
...
}
```

There is a config form to fill in the `my.config`'s values.

In the submit function of this form, I obviously save the config but after that, I would like to use `MyService`. Unfortunately, the config loaded by `MyService` doesn't contains the last changes encoded in the config form.

Not sure it is useful to know, but `MyService` is also loaded in `buildForm()`

Here is the submit function in which I am trying to invalidate `my.config`

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  ...
  $config->save();
  \Drupal::cache()->invalidate('my.config');
  \Drupal::cache()->invalidate('my.service');
  $my_service = Drupal::service('my.service');
  $my_service->useMyService(); // it will use the old values
}
```

Comment: Normally, after submitting a form, you redirect to a new page with all services loaded from scratch. It's more likely this is related to render caching where you need to include the cache tag of the config object. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays

Comment: I do not render anything in `useMyService()`... I don't know how to use `addCacheableDependency` as I do not have a renderer.

Comment: This is a very unusual use case then. Normally the form handles the editable config object instantiated with the form object and the service the immutable version of the config object. If you really need to update the service within the submit request your service needs a setter method for the config object. Reset the config object in the config factory and load it again to set it in the service.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I will go with 2 steps: submitting the form will redirect to another form which will run the service.